# Android Gradle DSL method not found

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I'm new to Android and trying to import a project to Android Studio but I read all comments related to this error on StackOverflow but none of them works for me.

The thing I can't find any `SDK` to install `23.0.0 cr3` the only `SDK` available is `23.0.1` or higher.

It's really killing me and I spend 3 days to fix it, but I could not solve the issue.

Here is some screenshot for the error and the page that need to make the changes.

Build.gradle:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: could u post another build.gradle file which is under main directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the folder inside your build-tool sdk folder, is on path [YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH]\build-tools\23.0.1    <-- mine is 23.0.1

So change `buildToolsVerions` to "23.0.1". That should works

Hope it helps!!